# How to visually let the user know that something is selected?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

For example, I have a userControl that I want a user to be able to "Select".

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private void ptbImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectControl();
}

private void SelectControl()
{
    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(235, 243, 253);
}
```

If I have many controls inside of this user control things get messy soon! :P Is there a to globally wrap around every control? Like a Click event for everything inside the control. If there isn't I'll just manually create a click even for every control to globally capture input. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Are these controls from the same type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes...

You can link the event of each control to the same event method, like this:

```
ptbImage1.Click += new System.EventHandler(ptbImage_Click);
ptbImage2.Click += new System.EventHandler(ptbImage_Click);
ptbImage3.Click += new System.EventHandler(ptbImage_Click);
```

etc..

Answer (score 0):

In the form's InitializeComponent method you could run a foreach through every control on the form and set the Click eventhandler to ptbImage_Click

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (Control ctrl in yourContainerControl.Controls)  {
    ctrl.Click += new System.EventHandler(ctrl_Click);   
}
```

You can also capture events application-wide, and handle them before they are directed to the control itself.